# I Just Don't Know What to Say

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

> I must have been having a terrible time getting out my words during today's meeting. I found my notepad covered in nonsense! What was I trying to say?

```
tea        Sasquatch  unusual    frog       peptide    crime      goldfish
relevant   red        herring    democrat   caucus     water      aardvark
snout      ants       allies     British    axis       fifer      roar
lion       ablaze     arson      gig        icicle     cold       frozen
lull       night      dream      ignite     suspect    treaty     spy
foreign    criminal   crack      broken     elephant   type       keyboard
Xerox      paper      limpid     banana     lilies     failing    chemistry
redundant  obnoxious  caricature long       infinite   zoology    bird
spider     usurper    fake       grass      tiger      aftershock quake
```

**Hint 1:** (I've got a great idea for my next puzzle, so I'd like to get this one solved quickly lol).

> What happens when you look at something while you're cross-eyed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have trouble speaking, then

> you can always say `supercalifragilisticexpialidocious`.

I am reliably informed that

> even though the sound of it is something quite atrocious, if you say it loud enough you'll always sound precocious.

And

> if you take the first repeated letter (if any) in each word, in order, then that's what you get.

Note: OP gave some heavy hints in [TSL chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50614090#50614090) as well as here...

Comment: Yay! Congratulations, and um-diddle-dee, um-diddle-li! Like I said, I have an idea for my next puzzle that I am _very_ excited about, so I wanted to expedite the solving of this one. And "reliably informed" XD.